# echo a string with a variable in it and the variable which is also a string and variable and blank but not work

Tags: shell

i was constructing a function which ought to echo the message with right color, but in my code there seems doesn't work.

the code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
function green() {
  echo -e "\033[32m[ $1 ]\033[0m"
}


function software_is_installed() {
  local message="software is installed with name:"$1
  blue $message
}

green ssh
```

the output is not expected, but

```
[ software ]
```

but in another snippet of code it work out ok.
and the code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
function blue() {
  echo -e "\033[34m[ $1 ]\033[0m"
}

function file_or_dir_already_exists() {
  blue "file or directory: $1 already exists"
}

file_or_dir_already_exists ~/
```

and it outputs as expected, and the output like

```
[ file or directory: ~/ already exists ]
```

i was expecting something like

```
software is installed with name: ssh
```

Comment: Why would `file_or_dir_already_exists ~/` invoke `software_is_installed`? They are two separate functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function green() {
  echo -e "\033[32m[ $1 ]\033[0m"
}


function software_is_installed() {
  green "software is installed with name: $1"
}

software_is_installed ssh
```

Comment: yep, this is a way to solve , but i wonder what's wrong with my first snippet of code. why can not i fix it.

Comment: For one thing, you put $1 outside the string itself. Then, you called blue (instead of green) in software_is_installed(). Lastly, you called green at the end of the file (which was the main reason it was only outputting [ ssh ]). Hope that helps.